# What type of shelving should I use in my basement?

Tags: shelving, replacement, storage, saving-money

We currently have single track brackets on a set of shelves 14 feet long & about ~7 feet high, with 6 upright posts. These need to be replaced with something much stronger.

The options I know about are:

1. Double track brackets with [these wire shelves](http://www.flowwall.com/PRODUCTS/Flow-Wall-Storage-Systems-Metal-Bracket-Shelf-Pack-White.html?utm_medium=cse&utm_source=amazon)
2. Shelving units, with either [wooden shelves](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B006941Z6E) or [metal shevles](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B0007MHD1K)

The shelves should be adjustable so that rules out #2, but I don't know if they're strong enough for standard basement storage (no shed or garage). Is #1 good enough or are there other options out there?

Comment: The metal type shelves that you linked to in #2 are generally available with the shelves adjustable at every 1 inch of height!!

Comment: I didn't know that. Now, balancing strength with cost, which is the best bang for the buck?

Comment: Determine your maximum weight requirements and identify the lowest cost system capable of supporting that. Extra strength is a waste and lesser strength will not meet your needs.

Comment: I don't know how much weight.

Comment: The best bang for the buck as you say is often related to how much of your own effort you put into it. Wire shelves are pretty good for many things but can really stink for things that want to slip in between the wires.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best rugged shelving that I've used in the basement and garage is called "rivet lock" shelving. This type is quite sturdy, has adjustable shelves and can be easily disassembled and moved.

When you go to search out this type make sure to get genuine rivet lock shelving. There are cheaper shelves that try to imitate the rivet lock type but are flimsy and prone to bending and damage if trying to disassemble/reassemble.

Here are a few pictures of some rivet lock shelving in my garage showing some of its features. In this first picture see how I added 3/8" plywood sides to the shelf by bolting it onto the side rails.

[image]

This next picture you can see how the shelf units are placed side by side (and in my case bolted together) to make up a bigger storage area. In this case the shelves for a U shaped space for tool storage. I have even placed a "floor" over the top to permit storage of other items overhead below the ceiling. The bottom side of the "floor" has a pair of small florescent lights to light the area.

[image]

This picture shows a closeup of the rivets and how the cross members slide into the side rails.

[image]

You can get this shelving at various home DIY stores. Once again be aware that it will be varying grades at different price points. I always get the product that has two rivets on each cross member. It is much stronger and sturdier.

(The shelving you see in the pictures has been moved across the country and reassembled several times. Note that the particle board shelf inserts come with the shelf kits).

Comment: I choose these especially if they travel and reassemble themselves.

Comment: These are legit shelves. Enamel coated, heavy duty, made to hold a lot of weight.

Comment: Are "narrow" ones (3 - 4 feet wide) better than "wide" (more than 4 feet)?

Comment: What company are yours?

Comment: Some of mine came from Sears and others from some local "big box" store. All of them have shelves that are 18"x36". I would not want them bigger than that because then the vertical height of the cross members gets a lot bigger.

Comment: "Big Box" like Home Depot?

Comment: Knox Lumber Supply.